# Nextjs v13 Revalidate by path not working

Tags: next.js

I am trying to implement ISR in a nextjs app. I am using firebase as the backend for this project and when loading data for some static pages I want to use the firebase admin sdk. However, the page never get revalidated when I attempt to revalidate by path. When I change use the firestore REST api and revalidate by tag, everything works as expected. Is there any reason for revalidate by path not working?

Here is the Page.tsx

```js
import { adminFirestore } from "../../firebaseAdmin.config";
import { DocumentSnapshot } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ college: "umich" }, { college: "msu" }, { college: "gvsu" }];
}

async function getCollegeData(college: string) {
    const data = await adminFirestore
      .collection("colleges")
      .doc(college)
      .collection("test")
      .get();

    return data.docs.map((doc: DocumentSnapshot) => doc.data());
}

export default async function College({
  params,
}: {
  params: { college: string };
}) {
  const data = await getCollegeData(params.college);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((obj: any, i: number) => (
        <h1 key={i}>{obj?.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the revalidate function

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache";

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const path = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("path") || "/";
  console.log(path);
  revalidateTag(path);
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
}
```

I pass in /msu, /gvsu, or /umich and nothing seems to work. The revalidate by tag works locally with next build, but not for preview on vercel.

Comment: Well I know it's late but first, if you want to try revalidate by path Why did you use `revalidateTag` instead of `revalidatePath` ??

Comment: Oops that was a typo, I did try both and neither worked, but I switched to the pages directory for api it started working

Comment: yea I also have the same issue, and have to use some workaround, looks like it's a known issue from there repo and it's now on the top prioritie they have to resolve.

Comment: @ShueiYang So revalidating a page or post won't work for you too? I have. Webhook integrated inside my app returns oke, data is changed but never revalidated from Next js side.

Comment: @Galanthus I see.. for now I put revalidatePath on the routeHandler, but I also use the route.refresh() to force to refresh the page...

Comment: Hi mates, just to comment something that maybe you already know

I was working well with revalidatePath in form actions when the current path of the user is the same that i revalidate.

But when I started to apply intercepting routes to put the form in other route, the revalidatePath crash showing this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.